# Combining 2 SELECT query using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-framework, join, left-join

How do i combined this to two select query using left join syntax. (My query has error and I can't find a solution)

```
select
    *
from
    (select
        mi.parent_entity_id entity,
        tctp.institution_rec_id institutionRecId,
        institution_code storecode,
        institution_name storename,
        case when sum(unsettled_points) is null
            then coalesce (sum(point_value),0)
            else coalesce
        (sum(unsettled_points),0) end sumpoints
     from
        t_card_transaction_point tctp
     inner join
        m_institution mi on tctp.institution_rec_id=mi.institution_rec_id
     where
        mi.parent_entity_id = 70125 and
        tctp.point_status = 'xy4604'
     group by
        entity,
        institutionRecId,
        storecode,
        storename
    ) storeExpired

left join
    entityExpired on storeExpired.entity=entityExpired.entity

(select
    mpb.institution_rec_id entity,
    tctd.institution_rec_id institutionRecId,
    tctd.card_no cardnumber,
    total_amount_primary totalpoints,
    case when total_unsettled_points is null
        then point_value
        else tctd.total_unsettled_points end
    points
 from
    t_card_transaction_detail tctd inner
 join
    m_point_bucket mpb on mpb.card_no=tctd.card_no
 inner join
    m_institution mi on mi.institution_rec_id=tctd.institution_rec_id
 where
    mpb.total_amount_primary > 1000 and
    tctd.adjustment_date is null
 group by
    entity,
    institutionRecId,
    cardnumber,
    totalpoints,
    points
) entityExpired
```

Comment: is using UNION the solution

Comment: No. I need is to combine them using left join.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 5: (select mpb.institution_rec_id entity, tctd.institution_rec_...
         ^

Here.
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 599

Comment: Well - your syntax is very wrong where you do a select after the left join - so I'll advice you to start smaller and then do the joins along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly:
We do appreciate proper indenting / lining of code for ease of readability :)

Second:
"My query has error" is not particularly explanatory.

Anywho, to answer your question:

SQL has an order of operation of

1. From
2. Where
3. Group By
4. Having
5. Select
6. Order By

This means that the alias are created when the select is executed. And since "group by" is executed before this, the alias's doesn't exist yet - this is probably the error you are getting.

Also, I'm not sure if MySQL does allow a join on a alias, which is defined further down in the query (I could be wrong though), so i would move the query itself into the join brackets, and use on the "on"-clause afterwards.

Sample query: (Not tested, since I doesn't have the tables)

```
select 
* 
from (
   select 
     mi.parent_entity_id      as entity
   , tctp.institution_rec_id  as institutionRecId
   , institution_code         as storecode
   , institution_name         as storename
   , case when sum(unsettled_points) is null 
      then coalesce (sum(point_value),0) 
      else coalesce (sum(unsettled_points),0) 
   end                        as sumpoints 
   from t_card_transaction_point tctp 
   inner join m_institution      mi on tctp.institution_rec_id = mi.institution_rec_id 
   where 1=1
   and mi.parent_entity_id = 70125 
   and tctp.point_status = 'xy4604' 
   group by 
     mi.parent_entity_id
   , tctp.institution_rec_id
   , institution_code
   , institution_name
) storeExpired
left join (
   select 
     mpb.institution_rec_id   as entity
   , tctd.institution_rec_id  as institutionRecId
   , tctd.card_no             as cardnumber
   , total_amount_primary     as totalpoints
   , case when total_unsettled_points is null 
      then point_value 
      else tctd.total_unsettled_points 
   end                        as points 
   from t_card_transaction_detail tctd 
   inner join m_point_bucket      mpb  on mpb.card_no=tctd.card_no 
   inner join m_institution       mi   on mi.institution_rec_id=tctd.institution_rec_id 
   where 1=1
   and mpb.total_amount_primary > 1000 
   and tctd.adjustment_date is null 
   group by 
     mpb.institution_rec_id
   , tctd.institution_rec_id
   , tctd.card_no
   , total_amount_primary
   , case when total_unsettled_points is null 
      then point_value 
      else tctd.total_unsettled_points 
   end
) entityExpired on storeExpired.entity=entityExpired.entity
```

**Edit:**
I just google'd it, and you can in fact use alias's in your group by statement in MySQL (Not allowed in MSSQL, nor is it ANSI standard).

However, after seeing your comment regarding the error, it is probably due to the fact that you are joining with the alias entityExpired, before the subquery is created. I'm guessing that moving the subquery, as I've done in the example, should work.

Comment: Hi Gunnar, Thank you. I think this is right. Output is now properly displayed. Next time, i will post question easy to read and with proper lining and indention.